# Launching new instance in CC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Anyone used CC2 machine?
What is the cost of the small instance for an hour?
If anyone used, can you share the environmental experience, so that I can start launching the new instance for testing?

Also, is there any micro instance available for testing purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You can get answers to the cost (for a small isntance) and testing (free tier) questions on the AWS site: http://aws.amazon.com/ - it depends on the region and OS.

Everyone can have a single micro instance available for free to try (the 'free tier') and everything else is fairly cheap for short period to try; you'll only get charged for each hour your instance is running.

Unless you have very specific, very demanding processing needs, and a decent budget, the CC2 instance type is overkill.

The general environment for EC2 is fairly easy-to-use, you should just give it a go, or do some research with Google.